# Why is the timeout error untraceable on App Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have a request to gather insights as follows for timeouts from asp.net web applications hosted on Azure App Service

- Date
- Time (by at least hour)
- API Endpoint

Ideally, this would also include a way to distinguish by:

- Default API endpoint
- API endpoint using filter

Basically the ultimate goal is to track down the root cause of numerous timeout alerts we keep getting.

Basically, we are able to identify some of the issues/alerts we get and trace them on the app insights, but for some reason, we are unable to trace timeouts on the app insights

**Traceable alert:**

[image: alert1]

**Non-traceable alert:**

[image: alert2]

I've considered Kusto queries, but I'm not sure what the formula would be to create metrics discussed above.

This is the full untraceable error for reference:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Generated: Fri, 19 Nov 2021 13:30:41 GMT

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at Ideal.Infrastructure.Data.Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryInternal>d__34`1.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\edgemvc-ideal\Ideal.Infrastructure.Data\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 697
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Ideal.Reporting.DynamicDataService.GetDataWithFilterSingular(String procName, BaseFilterParams filterParams) in C:\Projects\edgemvc-ideal\Ideal.ReportService\DynamicDataService.cs:line 28
at Ideal.Reporting.ReportingService.PracticeBreakoutReportPro(String section, BaseFilterParams filters, String schema) in C:\Projects\edgemvc-ideal\Ideal.ReportService\ReportingService.cs:line 248
at Ideal.API.Controllers.ReportController.PracticeBreakoutSectionPro(FilterParams filters, String descriptionId, String section) in C:\Projects\edgemvc-ideal\Ideal.API\Controllers\ReportController\ReportController.cs:line 81
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:9963f70a-f829-4b28-9655-4e256156f4bd
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
```

---

### Edit

I have tried looking for the exception in Log Analytics per suggestion, but it's still not traceable:

[image: LA]

Comment: Have you tried pulling the sql timeout exception using exception table in the log analytics workspace & also try  create a customer alert using that query. 

Here is the reference [blog](http://blogs.recneps.net/post/Querying-Exception-Logs-in-Azure-Log-Analytics) on how to query exception under exception table in log analytic workspace

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT hi Venkata, I have tried the Log Analytics suggestion. please see my edit

Comment: (Hi Cataster. Could I trouble you to run your question and answer posts through a spell-checker please? Posts here are for the long term, and are intended to benefit many future readers.)

Comment: @halfer oh sure, is there someway i can do that through SO automated bot?

Comment: I don't believe so. Certainly in my browser (Firefox) the edit box offers red-squiggle underlines for misspellings, but if you normally use a non-English language, you'll have to reset it in some fashion to any English variant (it doesn't matter which one - British, US, Canadian, Indian etc). Thanks!

Comment: @DeepDave-MT nope, still waiting for an answer

Comment: @DeepDave-MT i have posted in the Q/A forums before and someone responded to me but it was an incomplete/ambigious answer, so i replied back and its been a couple days im waiting on a response. I just tweeted at Azure Support on twitter. I could consider raising a ticket in the portal, but would it incur costs? or is the support free if we already have a pay-as-you-go subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also unable to find some of these timeouts in the Performance/Failure tabs under Application Insights for my particular App Service.

However, after I implemented [Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript) (Javascript) on my frontend:

- I think I'm able to find them for each Page in my application, using Log Analytics:
- ```
  pageViews
  | where duration > 25000 and client_Type == "Browser"
  | sort by timestamp, count_sum
  ```

  where `25000` equals 25 seconds, a threshold for our timeouts.
- It seems that backend requests are traced automatically in the `requests` table, so no extra implementation on frontend required:

  ```
  requests
  | where duration > 25000
  | summarize count_sum = count() by bin(timestamp,1d), operation_Name, name
  | sort by timestamp, count_sum
  ```

Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure about the correctness, but at least it has helped me a bit. The documentation on Application Insights is a bit complex I feel.

Comment: interesting, can you elaborate more on the steps for this? `data from App Insights SDK on my frontend`